# Inequality for sum of functions defined on power set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Consider $x_1, \ldots , x_N \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $p_1, ..., p_N \in \{0,1\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i = 1$.

Consider $f : \mathcal{P}\left( \{ x_1, \ldots, x_N \}\right) \rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\mathcal{P}\left( \{ x_1, \ldots, x_N \}\right) := \left\{ \{x_1\}, \ldots, \{x_N\}, \{x_1, x_2\}, \{x_1, x_3\}, \ldots, \{ x_{N-1}, x_N \}, \{ x_1, x_2, x_3 \}, \ldots  \right\}$.

Say under what additional conditions the following inequality is true.
$$ \sum_{i_1=1}^N \sum_{i_2=1}^N f\left( \{ x_{i_1}, x_{i_2} \} \right) p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \geq \sum_{i_1=1}^N \sum_{i_2=1}^N \sum_{i_3=1}^N f\left( \{ x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, x_{i_3} \} \right) p_{i_1} p_{i_2} p_{i_3}. $$

Comment. The LHS can be also written as follows.
$$ \sum_{i_1=1}^N \sum_{i_2=1}^N f\left( \{ x_{i_1}, x_{i_2} \} \right) p_{i_1} p_{i_2} = \sum_{i_1=1}^N \sum_{i_2=1}^N \sum_{i_3=1}^N f\left( \{ x_{i_1}, x_{i_2} \} \right) p_{i_1} p_{i_2} p_{i_3}. $$

Comment: Your notation hints that you're omitting the empty set from the list of members of the power set.  It is certainly one of the members.

Comment: Your condition 1 makes no sense.  An input to $f$ should simply be a subset of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$, not a set of subsets of that set.  Might you have meant $f(\{x,y,x\})=f(\{x,y\})$ for all $x,y\in\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$?  Then it makes sense but it's vacuous: it doesn't really restrict the set of functions. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a set, there is no repetition of the elements. That is, the set $\{1,2\}$ is the same set as $\{1,1,2\}$ or $\{1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2\}$. So there is really no condition on $f$ and the inequality is not true in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640203/inequality-with-monotone-functions-on-power-set] I made my question more specific: $f$ is monotone. Perhaps you may be interested.