# Sequence of probabilities with monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, inequality

Let $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with finite support $S = \{ 1, 2, ..., N\}$. Let $P$ be the corresponding probability measure.

For all $k \geq 1$, define $A_k := \{ X_1, X_2, ..., X_k \}$, so that $A_k \subseteq A_{k+1}$.

Consider a monotone function $f: (\mathcal{P}(S) \setminus \varnothing) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $f$ is monotone: $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \Longrightarrow f(S_1) \leq f(S_2)$.
2. $f$ is determined only by $2$ elements in its argument.

Define $p_k := P^{k+1}\left[ f(A_{k+1}) > f(A_{k}) \right]$.

Say if there exists $\bar{k} \geq 2$ such that $p_k \geq p_{k+1}$ for all $k \geq \bar{k}$.

Comment. This question is a variant of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640203/inequality-with-monotone-functions-on-power-set), with an explicit assumption on $f$. CLearly, $p_k \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Of course $p_k\to0$, since almost surely $A_k=S$ for every $k$ large enough.

Comment: Therefore there is hope to find $\bar{k}$ such that $p_k$ is non-increasing for all $k \geq \bar{k}$. Please let me know if you may think about a proof.